# Can I use HTML5 Now to create a website

Tags: css, html

After all the latest news and talk about HTML5, I would like to know whether I can use HTML5 to create a website as of now. I mean, some features are supported by few browsers, while few features are not yet supported. So is it possible to create a full-fledged website at the current state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I built a site in 100% semantic HTML5, tested only in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. When I was done, I added these three scripts and loaded it up in IE6 and IE7 - <strike>looked pixel-perfect!</strike> ok, perfect is an exaggeration. It doesn't look exactly the same, but it looks fine e.g. no broken layout parts, everything is legible and functional.

- [**HTML5 Shiv script**](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) - Add HTML5 element support
- [**ExplorerCanvas**](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) - Add `<canvas>` support
- [**IE PNG Fix (IE6 only)**](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) - Add transparent PNG support

YMMV but these will almost certainly get you at least 90% of the way.

Comment: Do you have a link for this site?

Answer (score 10):

The question is not whether you can create a full-fledged website, but whether you need its functionality to be identical in all browsers. The answer to the former question is yes. The answer to the latter question is still no.

Answer (score 4):

As with all new technologies make sure your website degrades gracefully.

So don't use the new `<canvas>` tag as the main part of your website, but you can provide a little widget or something(which is not necessary or part of the main content) which uses it.

Or if you use the `<video>` tag make sure that you have a backup Flash way of viewing the video as well(especially since the codecs supported by `<video>` is completely fragmented at the moment!)

Make sure that people on older/IE browsers can still see what your site is about and ensure it looks decent to them. I have to do the same thing with the CSS3 features that I make use of in my work.

Comment: I would use canvas without dumbing it down for IE but provide a backup there. The video codecs are not entirely fragmented but now down to either H.264 or Ogg/Theora though the Ogg camp will switch over to VP8 over the next few months.

Answer (score 3):

I would say check your stats first..how many users are still on internet explorer and how important are those users to you. In other words if 80% of your users use a browser that doesn't support HTML5 then I would say don't do it

Answer (score 2):

You sure can.  I could write all the things you can do with HTML5 now, however I'll just link to a great article posted at http://html5doctor.com.

http://html5doctor.com/how-to-use-html5-in-your-client-work-right-now/

Answer (score 1):

Charlie yes it's possible, but like you said some features are supported by most modern browsers, although not all of the features are supported at the moment . Take a look here: http://html5demos.com/